# How can I loop through all the routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

From inside a mvc (2) user control, I want to loop through all the route values.

So if I have controllers like:

```
UserController
AccountController
```

I need a collection of the values that will appear in the url like:

```
/user/...
/account/...
```

i.e. the values user, account.

How can I get this?

I tried RouteTables but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: do you have a tree/graph of sorts?

Comment: The RouteTable is indeed the place to look... That said, we do it the other way around: we use attributes to advertise routes, and build the route-table via reflection - and we can of course run that reflection at whim to list the routes

Comment: sorry I'm referring to asp.net mvc routes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh, really a good question to keep my self busy for an hour.
To achieve the required functionality , we need to hook into MVC source and little bit of reflections.

1. By default Route names are not available , so we need to write a Route collection extension to save Route Name in RouteData tokens.

   ```
   public static Route MapRouteWithName(this RouteCollection routes,string name, string   url, object defaults=null, object constraints=null)
   {

   Route route = routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints);
   route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
   route.DataTokens.Add("RouteName", name);
   return route;
   }
   ```
2. Modify the global.asax maproute call to invoke previous extension

   ```
   routes.MapRouteWithName(
               "Default", // Route name
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
           );
   ```
3. Modified the MVC PathHelper a little bit.(Include this helper in the project)

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Specialized;
   using System.Web;

   public static class PathHelpers
   {

   // this method can accept an app-relative path or an absolute path for contentPath
   public static string GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, string contentPath)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentPath))
       {
           return contentPath;
       }

       // many of the methods we call internally can't handle query strings properly, so just strip it out for
       // the time being
       string query;
       contentPath = StripQuery(contentPath, out query);

       return GenerateClientUrlInternal(httpContext, contentPath) + query;
   }

   private static string GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, string contentPath)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentPath))
       {
           return contentPath;
       }

       // can't call VirtualPathUtility.IsAppRelative since it throws on some inputs
       bool isAppRelative = contentPath[0] == '~';
       if (isAppRelative)
       {
           string absoluteContentPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(contentPath, httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
           string modifiedAbsoluteContentPath = httpContext.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(absoluteContentPath);
           return GenerateClientUrlInternal(httpContext, modifiedAbsoluteContentPath);
       }

       string relativeUrlToDestination = MakeRelative(httpContext.Request.Path, contentPath);
       string absoluteUrlToDestination = MakeAbsolute(httpContext.Request.RawUrl, relativeUrlToDestination);
       return absoluteUrlToDestination;
   }

   public static string MakeAbsolute(string basePath, string relativePath)
   {
       // The Combine() method can't handle query strings on the base path, so we trim it off.
       string query;
       basePath = StripQuery(basePath, out query);
       return VirtualPathUtility.Combine(basePath, relativePath);
   }

   public static string MakeRelative(string fromPath, string toPath)
   {
       string relativeUrl = VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative(fromPath, toPath);
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(relativeUrl) || relativeUrl[0] == '?')
       {
           // Sometimes VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative() will return an empty string when it meant to return '.',
           // but links to {empty string} are browser dependent. We replace it with an explicit path to force
           // consistency across browsers.
           relativeUrl = "./" + relativeUrl;
       }
       return relativeUrl;
   }

   private static string StripQuery(string path, out string query)
   {
       int queryIndex = path.IndexOf('?');
       if (queryIndex >= 0)
       {
           query = path.Substring(queryIndex);
           return path.Substring(0, queryIndex);
       }
       else
       {
           query = null;
           return path;
       }
   }

   }
   ```
4. Add few Helper methods in controller

   ```
   public static string GenerateUrl(string routeName, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext)
   {

       RouteValueDictionary mergedRouteValues = MergeRouteValues(actionName, controllerName);

       VirtualPathData vpd = routeCollection.GetVirtualPathForArea(requestContext, routeName, mergedRouteValues);
       if (vpd == null)
       {
           return null;
       }

       string modifiedUrl = PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrl(requestContext.HttpContext, vpd.VirtualPath);
       return modifiedUrl;
   }
   public static RouteValueDictionary MergeRouteValues(string actionName, string controllerName)
   {
       // Create a new dictionary containing implicit and auto-generated values
       RouteValueDictionary mergedRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

       // Merge explicit parameters when not null
       if (actionName != null)
       {
           mergedRouteValues["action"] = actionName;
       }

       if (controllerName != null)
       {
           mergedRouteValues["controller"] = controllerName;
       }

       return mergedRouteValues;
   }
   ```
5. Now we can write some reflection logics to read controllers, actions and routenames.

   ```
   Dictionary<string, List<string>> controllersAndActions = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

   // Get all the controllers
   var controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(t));

   foreach (var controller in controllers)
   {
       List<string> actions = new List<string>();
       //Get all methods without HttpPost and with return type action result
       var methods = controller.GetMethods().Where(m => typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(m.ReturnType)).Where(a=>!a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpPostAttribute),true).Any());
       methods.ToList().ForEach(a => {
           actions.Add(a.Name);
       });
       var controllerName = controller.Name;
       if (controllerName.EndsWith("Controller"))
       {
           var nameLength = controllerName.Length - "Controller".Length;
           controllerName = controllerName.Substring(0, nameLength);
       }
       controllersAndActions.Add(controllerName, actions);
   }
   List<string> allowedRoutes = new List<string>();

   var routeNames = RouteTable.Routes.Where(o=>o.GetRouteData(this.HttpContext)!=null).Select(r=>r.GetRouteData(this.HttpContext).DataTokens["RouteName"].ToString());
   foreach (var cName in controllersAndActions)
   {
       foreach (var aName in cName.Value)
       {
           foreach (var item in routeNames)
           {
               allowedRoutes.Add(GenerateUrl(item, aName, cName.Key, RouteTable.Routes, this.Request.RequestContext));
           }
       }

   }
   ```
6. Points to remember :If in the route you have defined any default parameters, then url for those controller and action will be empty. e.g. in above example "/Home/Index" will be shown as "/"
7. Download the sample application [Link To Download](http://www.4shared.com/zip/D6R6cF6F/MvcApplication1.html)

   [image: List item]

Comment: Yes, took around an hour find a way

Comment: Awesome! This is what I figured would be required but didn't want to write it out. The only other solution I  know is to use FubuMVC. :) http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2010/01/04/fubumvc-diagnostics-sneak-peek/